# multipleCompilationError when parsing config file using ConfigSlurper

Tags: groovy, configuration-files

I need to access config file in my groovy code using ConfigSlurper as am using blocks inside the file to access each one depending on the user info !

so i need to use the properties in one block in the file ( based in the user info ) and set it to an object in my code !
I used something like this

```
def pc = ConfigSlurper().parse(newFile(configManager.config.priceInfo.filepath).toURI().toURL())
```

my file contains closures as blocks as following :

```
   employee {
    sth = 1 
    other =2 
    }

    student {
    sth = 10 
    other =20 }

default
{
sth = 100
other =200
}
```

I get multipleCompilationError exception when parsing the file !

Comment: What is your question? What isn't working? Is there an error? Also the "I used something like this" part does not help. Just post the exact code.

Comment: this is the exact code i used to parse the file ! and am getting multiCompilationError exception !

Comment: this is just cute.  in your own answer you show, that the error/exception (you failed to provide) comes from code, that you don't provide in your question.

Comment: i didn't think that would be a problem ! i provided a sample of my file ! the file is quite big and therefor it doesn't make sense to list all of it here

Answer (score -1):

i was using a block in my file with the name default !

```
employee {
sth = 1 
other =2 
}

student {
sth = 10 
other =20
}

default{
sth = 100 
other =200
}
```

This was causing this exception ! it seems like default is a keyword for a class in Groovy ! i changed 'default' to other name and it works now for me anyhow :)